# matplotloib: как отобразить значения в порядке возрастания, сохранив их индекс?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.6, matplotlib, график

Есть 2 списка `x` и `y`. `x` идет в порядке возрастания, `y`- хаотичный. Как отобразить ось `y` в порядке возрастания, но что бы значения (x,y) не поменялись?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x=[]
with open('D:\Programming\Contest\stepperf.txt','r') as a:
    for line in a:
        x.append(line.strip())
x =np.array(x)
y=[]
with open('D:\Programming\Contest\Hall.txt','r') as b:
    for line in b:
        y.append(line.strip())
y  = np.array(y)


fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8, 6))
plt.grid()     
plt.plot(x,y) 

plt.show()
```

Comment: Не понял вопроса. Как можно отобразить Y в порядке возрастания, но чтобы значения не поменялись? Просто отображайте себе значения и все.

Answer (score 1):

Можно воспользоваться функцией `numpy.argsort()`:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# x тут по порядку, а y случайные числа
n = 10
x = np.arange(n)
y = np.random.rand(n)

# сортируем индексы (x,y) по значениям y
ind = y.argsort()

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8, 6))
plt.grid()     
# рисуем в отсортированном порядке
plt.plot(x[ind],y[ind]) 

plt.show()
```

[image: sort_y]

Answer (score 0):

Тут нужно использовать библиотеку `numpy`, и библиотеку `pandas`
В библиотеке пандас есть возможность создать `data array` с индексом для каждой вещи.

```
Data = numpy.array(['a','b','s'])
S = pandas.Series(Data, index=[101,102,103])
```

Comment: Это всё хорошо, но у человека уже есть готовый `y`, что ему дальше делать? )